# Any way to efficiently reuse and optimize repeated code block in wrapper function?

Tags: r, optimization, functional-programming, r-s4

I have implemented several functions where some function behaved very similar way and share some identical structure. However, I intend to reuse the code more efficiently in my wrapper functions to make function body smaller for the sake of easy to test and debug. I am trying to find better way to construct my wrapper function as small as possible. How can I efficiently reuse the code multiple times in wrapper function easily ? What's the strategy to efficiently use same code structure in many times? Can anyone give me possible idea to overcome this issue ? Any idea ?

- Note: among the param list, `obj.List` could be list of data.frame, `intList` could be list of integer list as position index, `val.List` could be list of numeric vector, `threshold` could be numeric scalar.

This is the wrapper function where two small sub functions' code is shared same pattern :

```
myFunc <- function(obj.List, intList, threshold, ...) {
  # 
  func.1 <- function() {
    keepIdx <- lapply(intList, function(ele_) {
      keepMe <- sapply(val.List, function(x) x<=threshold)
      res <- ele_[keepMe]
    })
    expand.Keep <- Map(unlist, 
                       mapply(extractList, obj.List, keepIdx))
    return(expand.Keep)
  }
  func.2 <- function() {
    dropIdx <- lapply(intList, function(ele_) {
      drop_ <- sapply(val.List, function(x) x > threshold)
      res <- ele_[drop_]
    })
    expand.drop <- Map(unlist,
                       mapply(extractList, obj.List, keepIdx))
    return(expand.drop)
  }
  # then use the output of func.1 and func.2 as an argument for another function 
  # in this wrapper
  # how can I make this wrapper more efficient ? How to resue the code ?
}
```

I am just trying to make function body of this wrapper smaller, while I can call func.1, func.2 as an argument in the wrapper to trigger another sub function. How can I make this happen ? Any way efficiently optimize the code structure of above wrapper function ?

Comment: Use more function formals, so `function.1()` could be something like `function.1(intList)`. This way you can declare it outside of the function and it will make the code components much more readable/safe.

Answer (score 0):

As I said earlier, use more formals. It makes it clearer how individual components work and allows you to break apart your code more easily.

I haven't been able to test to see if this works as a working example was not provided, but here is one example of how you could begin to break this apart.

```
# This function mirrors most of what func.1 and func.2 do
unlistAndSelect <- function(intList, val.list, threshold, selection.method) {

    # Making use of declaring other variables in lapply
    keepIdx <- lapply(intList, selectionFunction,
                      val.list = val.list, threshold = threshold,  
                      selection.fun = selection.method)

    # unlist
    expand.Keep <- Map(unlist, mapply(extractList, obj.List, keepIdx))

    # Return result
    return(expand.Keep)
}

# Mirrors most of dropIdx and keepIdx passing a selection method
selctionFunction <- function(ele_, val.list, selection.fun) {
    keepMe <- sapply(val.List, selection.fun)
    res <- ele_[keepMe]
}

# Your two selection methods
selectGEQ <- function(x) x <= threshold
selectLT <- function(x) x > threshold

# unlistAndSelect(... , selection.method = selectGEQ) will have similar results to function 1
# unlistAndSelect(... , selection.method = selectLT) will have similar results to function 1

myFunc <- function(obj.List, intList, threshold, ...) {


    # then use the output of func.1 and func.2 as an argument for another function 
    # in this wrapper
    # how can I make this wrapper more efficient ? How to resue the code ?
}
```

I should also note that I think you can rewrite the selection methods, but I haven't in this instance as you would need to be careful with the data structures you are handing them.

Comment: I think you could just hand over `<` or `<=` and avoid writing the wrapper functions selectGEQ and selectLT

Comment: For example you would do this in the function formals `unlistAndSelect(..., selection.method = \`<\`)`

Comment: Hard to see how without a reproducible example of what exactly you are doing.